# reading double word for translation

Tags: php, vb.net, string

we are designing translation project from Sindhi to English, in Sindhi (Pakistani/Indus) Language their are so many words with double word or having space bw them but have one meaning like in English to eat. it is two word, but have single meaning. I want to design a program to read starting double word, search it in database if meaning found then put and read next double word, and if meaning not found then read first word and find meaning, if found meaning then read next two words after first single word. for example I want to do this

this is simple sentence

I want to eat a mango.
I want to PHP or visual basic.net to break it into this style

I want
I
want to
want
to eat
to
eat mango
eat
mango

with this example all words are read both in single and double style.

I have some hints

use loop for `(i=0, i<=length of text, i++)`

sense word sepration where space or panctuation marks are used
coding may be

```
str=substr(text, i, 1)
```

if str is= " " or str= punctuation marks (space or punctuation mark is the word separators) 
but remember we first have to read first two words so read while spaces become two
echo or print such dobule word. 
word reading may be like this
word length (wrdlen) is equal to i variable of for loop and after usage it become 0 when word is made by strings

```
tillword = substr(text, i-wrdlen, wordlen)
```

these are some hints i'm hanged up please help any one. so with the help of above hints I need these results form

I want to eat a mango. 
I want
I
want to
want
to eat
to
eat mango
eat
mango

You may think this double word language philosophy from any secondary language you know that double word may contain single meaning, or some times single word is meaning less, like in English there is "to"

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I correctly understand but from what I get you want to be able to translate on basis of a multiple word phrase instead of single words. This is kinda similar to what language parsers do while compiling or interpreting.

One simple way to implement this functionality would be to first break down the sentence into words. In python this can be done very simply with something like:

```
words = sentence.split(' ')
```

Now you can try parsing these words by looping through them and storing them in a queue. The trick is to remember what was entered and have defined rules.

Let me give you an example. Let's say your sentence is "to eat a mango"

The rules of your language translation are (assumed):
to eat - X

to drink - XZ

mango - Y

So you loop through the words and enter them into a queue. After performing this step your queue will have

mango

a

eat

to

You can then start popping out elements. The first element to pop out is 'to'. Now check if there are phrases that start with 'to' if so store it in a string and go to the next element which is 'eat'. Concatenate this with the original string with a space. So you get "to eat" which matches a rule "to get" -> X so now translate and return X.
Alternatively if hadn't had matched then you translate the original string "to" return it and create a new string with the new element and continue.

Hope this helps.